# Trying to add slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I am trying to do is add some slides to my currently slideshow. It was originally 9 slides only but I'm having to add some slides. At first I thought it was as simple as changing

```
slider.slides = 9;
```

to

```
slider.slides = 11;
```

but this is proving difficult as the extra slides are not displaying but the original 9 are.

I'll add the jQuery I am using and hopefully it's something to do with that. If not, I'll go ahead and get a JSFiddle together.

```
var slider = {};
        slider.current = 1;
        slider.slides = 11;
        slider.goto = function (slideNumber, callback) {
            var difference = Math.abs(this.current - slideNumber);
            this.current = slideNumber;

            $('#slides').stop().animate({
                left: (-(slideNumber-1)*100) + '%'
            }, 400*difference, callback);

            $('a[href^="#slide-"]').parent().removeClass('active');
            $('a[href="#slide-' + slideNumber + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
        }

        slider.prev = function(){
            if(this.current > 1) {
                var slideNumber = Number(this.current)-1;
                this.goto(slideNumber);
            }
        }

        slider.next = function(){
            if(this.current < this.slides) {
                var slideNumber = Number(this.current)+1;
                this.goto(slideNumber);
            }
        }

        $('a').bind('click', function(event){
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
            if (link.indexOf('#slide-') != -1) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var slideNumber = link.replace('#slide-','');
                if (slideNumber == 'next') {
                    slider.next();
                } else if (slideNumber == 'prev') {
                    slider.prev();
                } else {
                    slider.goto(slideNumber);
                }
            }
        });

        $(window).keydown(function(event){
            if(event.keyCode == 39) {
                slider.next();
            } else if (event.keyCode == 37) {
                slider.prev();
            }
        });
```

Here is the nav

```
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#slide-1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-4">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-5">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-6">6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-7">7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-8">8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-9">9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-10">10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-11">11</a></li>
        <li><a href="/resources/">Back</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I hope this is enough to go with if not let me know.

[Heres the Jsfiddle anyway http://jsfiddle.net/cry4gLn6/1/ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following to your javascript:

```
$('#slides').css('width', (slider.slides * 100) + '%');
$('.slide').css('width', (100 / slider.slides) + '%');
```

This will dynamically calculate the total widths required for your slider to work with any number of slides. I have updated [your fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cry4gLn6/2/).

Comment: Thats Perfect. Thank You Jamie.

Answer (score 1):

You will just need to update the width of the `#slides` div

Currently its `900%`

If this width is calculated dynamically using jquery depending on the no. slides, your slider will work for any no. of slides.

Comment: Ah i see now! anyway you could guide me in the right direction to do this?